# how to display data in a angularjs form when two checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a form which contains 4 checkboxes -

> ■ angularjs ■ jquery ■ ruby ■ Do nothing

In my controller there is a `$watch` service that is keeping track of the checkbox that is getting clicked.

```
 $scope.$watch("formData.displayOption", function(displayOption) {
        if(displayOption) {
          var value1 = displayOption.angularJs,
              value2 = displayOption.jquery,
              value3 = displayOption.ruby,
              value4 = displayOption.doNothing;

          console.log(value1, value2, value3, value4);

          $scope.pages = null;
          $scope.message = null;

          if (value1 === true ) {
            $scope.pages = groupOne;
          } else if (value2 === true) {
            $scope.pages = groupTwo;
          } else if (value3 === true) {
            $scope.pages = groupThree;
          } else {
            $scope.message = 'No Options';
          }
        }
      }, true);
```

and the **groupOne,groupTwo,groupThree** that i am assigning to $scope.pages is

```
  var groupOne = [
    { name: 'js'},
    { name: 'angjs'},
    { name: 'angularjs'}
  ];

  var groupTwo = [
    { name: 'jquery'},
    { name: 'jquery-ui'}
  ];
  var groupThree = [
    { name: 'Ruby'}
  ];
```

So when **angularjs is checked -> groupOne** is displayed similarly for **jquery->groupTwo** & **ruby->groupThree**

What i am trying to do is when two checkboxes are ticked i want to display both the data corresponding to the checked box and similarly when the checkbox is unchecked i want the data to disappear. 
Like if **✓ angularjs and ✓ jquery** then the displaying data should be

- js
- angjs
- angularjs
- jquery
- jquery-ui

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCJMAVp9GzJXdn8Px9nJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` to append each selected item into `$scope.pages`. Change your `if-else` block in the `watch` to:

```
if (value1 === true ) {
    $scope.pages = groupOne;
} if (value2 === true) {
    $scope.pages = $scope.pages.concat(groupTwo);
} if (value3 === true) {
    $scope.pages = $scope.pages.concat(groupThree);
} if(!value1 && !value2 && !value3) {
    $scope.message = 'No Options';
}
```

Updated the plunker [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8cL5vM1TRinWSOy11PHl?p=preview)

**EDIT:**
Also, instead of `$scope.pages = null;` have `$scope.pages = [];` in your watch.

Comment: Thanks! but , If we select the 2nd checkbox first nothing displays.. how to solve that?

Comment: @GandharvGarg please follow up a question with a response. Did you find it correct? If not, then a comment.